# Multiple GridBagConstraints?

Tags: java, gridbaglayout

I'm a bit confused, is it possible to have multiple **`GridBagConstraints`**?

I have two panels using **`GridBagLayout`**, both affected by the same constraints. This gives me an issue when it comes to putting smaller components next to larger ones as illustrated below. The size of the panel on the left, means the cell on that row is very large, centering the panel on the right and it's components. I've tried using separate constraints for each panel but I haven't seen any differences, I think I'm doing something wrong.

How can I achieve two panels positioned next to each other, however have the components of each influenced by separate constraints?

Here's what I currently have:

[image]

Created with:

```
    // layout
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    // components
    JPanel supplier = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

    // grab the suppliers
    Suppliers.Supplier[] suppliers = new Suppliers.Supplier[Suppliers.supplier.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < Suppliers.supplier.size(); i++) {
        suppliers[i] = Suppliers.supplier.get(i);
    }

    JPanel resultsPanel = new JPanel();
        JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(resultsPanel, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
            scrollpane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120, 300));

        // style properties
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 0;
            c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);

    supplier.add(scrollpane, c);

    int position = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < Suppliers.supplier.size(); i++) {


        b_supplierSuppliers.add(new JButton(suppliers[i].getName()));
            b_supplierSuppliers.get(i).setActionCommand(suppliers[i].getId());
            b_supplierSuppliers.get(i).addActionListener(this);

        // style properties
           c.gridx = 0;
           c.gridy = position;
           c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
           c.gridwidth = 1;

        resultsPanel.add(b_supplierSuppliers.get(i), c);

        position++;

    }

    JPanel resultsPaneltwo = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

    // style properties
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;

    supplier.add(resultsPaneltwo, c);

    // code label
    l_supplierCode = new JLabel("Supplier Code");

        // style properties
            c.gridx = 1;
            c.gridy = 0;
            c.insets = new Insets(0, 10, 10, 10);
            c.gridwidth = 4;
            c.fill = 4;

        resultsPaneltwo.add(l_supplierCode, c);
```

However I'm after:

[image]

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please put the picture of the panel.How it want to appear.

Comment: The second picture is exactly what you are asking for @ShihabSoft. Be sure to read the whole question.

Comment: If this issue has been solved don't forget to accept and upvote an answer. If none of the current answers do the job, you can post your own answer and accept that. This helps anyone who might stumble across your question in the future. :)

Answer (score 1):

First, to answer your initial question. Yes, you should use different `GridBagConstraints` objects for each component. It's worth noting however that it is not **essential** to create new ones for each component, and changes to the constraint after it has been assigned to another won't affect the earlier component's position. So, for the sake of readability and later debugging it is worth declaring multiple constraints but it's not essential.

Also, it looks as though you need to specify a `weighty` for your constraint on your right cell. By default cells are centered in any spare space. In order to specify where that extra space is placed (*vertically for y, and horizontally for x*), you need to give the constraint a weight value;

```
c.weighty = 1;
```

This should make it so all extra vertical space is allocated to that cell's constraint, and as such push the cell to the top. If you create a second constraint and do the following;

```
c2.weighty = 1;
```

The extra space would be spread evenly between those two cell's constraints.I hope this helps. Let me know how you get on.

The official [Oracle GridBagLayout guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) says the following on the weight attributes;

> **weightx, weighty**
>
> Specifying weights is an art that can have a
>   significant impact on the appearance of the components a GridBagLayout
>   controls. Weights are used to determine how to distribute space among
>   columns (weightx) and among rows (weighty); this is important for
>   specifying resizing behavior. Unless you specify at least one non-zero
>   value for weightx or weighty, all the components clump together in the
>   center of their container. This is because when the weight is 0.0 (the
>   default), the GridBagLayout puts any extra space between its grid of
>   cells and the edges of the container.
>
> Generally weights are specified with 0.0 and 1.0 as the extremes: the
>   numbers in between are used as necessary. Larger numbers indicate that
>   the component's row or column should get more space. For each column,
>   the weight is related to the highest weightx specified for a component
>   within that column, with each multicolumn component's weight being
>   split somehow between the columns the component is in. Similarly, each
>   row's weight is related to the highest weighty specified for a
>   component within that row. Extra space tends to go toward the
>   rightmost column and bottom row.

Comment: Also, as an aside, I haven't used `GridBagLayout` for a little while now. If anyone spots any necessary amendments to this answer let me know so I can correct them.

Comment: Thank you for the fast and detailed reply. Your suggestion along with achor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH on the panel fixed the issue. Many thanks.